# Moving object warps it

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode

I have a cup that I made and I'm trying to move the bottom part along the z axis. I click on the edges using alt + click and press g and then z to move it, but when I do that, the bottom is able to move up and down but it ends up moving it in a really weird way (it moves toward my direction and up/down). What setting do I change so that I can fix this?

The object has a solidify and subdivision surface modifier attaches but removing them doesn't change anything so I don't think that has to do with this.
This is what happens when I try to move the bottom along the z axis while facing the cup
[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Maby it has something to do with "Transform Orientation" or maby even a simple Keyboardlayout-Language-Changeup (engl. <> eu)

Comment: I think you're moving along the local z axis, not world

Comment: If you want to move the entire thing in edit mode, why not just press A to select all?

Comment: @EricXue I'm trying to move the bottom of the cup so that it touches the ground, while keeping the top of the cup in the same place as the reference. I managed to move it down though but the problem itself isn't solved

Comment: @AM Where can I find those settings?

Comment: The file should be shared now. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=LdjG1AW7" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/LdjG1AW7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the file.  When I went into Edit Mode, I couldn't select anything for some reason, so I wasn't able to test your exact problem, but I noticed that in Object Mode the whole cup does exactly what you're describing, and I figured out why it's doing that, and it would affect Edit Mode transformations as well.

You have snapping turned on; that's the magnet button up at the top of the viewport.  That is constraining the selection to your floor plane.  So you're trying to move it in the Z axis, but that is exactly what it *cannot* do while it's set to be snapped to the floor plane, and so it just moves in whatever axes it can.  Turn off snapping, and it behaves normally.